# Why does electric flux only consider normal components of electric fields?

Tags: electric-fields, gauss-law

According to the definition of electric flux, only the normal components of field lines passing through a surface are considered. I am unable to understand why it's so? What would be different or wrong if the definition included field lines in any direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only vector components that are normal to a surface will actually pass through it.

For an oblique vector and a surface, only the normal component of the vector "passes through". The in-surface component is inconsequential.

Comment: would the downvoter care to elaborate?

Comment: Hi, could you please explain a little more about why the in-surface component is inconsequential? (p.s. - I didn't downvote your answer)

Comment: @LightBreeze The in-plane component of the vector just forever points along the plane, but never "passes through".. Only the normal component of the vector passes through. So if you have either a straight-normal or a (larger) oblique flux, both with the same normal component, their effects would be identical in context of a physical phenomenon that relates to how much of said flux passes through a certain area. Similar arguments apply to magnetic induction, with magnetic field passing through a loop area, and many other effects

Comment: Maybe an intuitive example..The sun always shines at the same power. But it heats a surface most effectively when that surface points straight to it, because then the sun irradiation has the largest normal component with respect to that surface. To obtain the same effect for oblique incidence, the sun would have to be stronger. But it is always the same strength, so oblique incidence heats less.

Comment: yeah but the oblique incidence still has some effect right? could you please give a little more in-depth explanation about how the in-plane component just forever points along the plane? didn't quite get that